# Blank columns in results when there shouldn't be sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

First of all: I apologize in advance for my dumb question. I am using sqlite3 for the first time and am rusty with sql, so I am hoping for some help. I have a small support ticket tracking database from which I would like to use to create metrics. I am running into trouble pulling information in a viewable format using the three tables I have.

```
tickets         ticket_changes     ticket_history
==================================================
ticket_id       history_id         history_id
description     ticket_id          edited_by
created_by                         field_event
account_id                         old_value
contact_id                         new_value
product
```

What I would like to be able to do is search for specific events and pull details about that ticket. For example, if a ticket is assigned to the tier 2 team, there is a record of that in ticket_history. The old_value would be the group to which it was assigned and new_value would be Tier 2. For the tickets that were assigned to tier 2, I want to know the ticket number, when it was opened, who opened it, etc. Ideally, the results would look something like this:

```
ticket_number | created_by | created_date    | tier2_assignment | product
===========================================================================
1234            jdoe        2018-01-01 00:00 2018-01-01 00:35  blue widget
1235            dsmith      2018-01-01 01:00  2018-01-02 12:01 green widget
```

I have tried pivot using `CASE`, but I don't think I know enough to make it work.

```
SELECT t.ticket_number, t.created_by,
       CASE WHEN (th.field_event = 'Created.') THEN th.edit_date END AS created_date,
       CASE WHEN (th.new_value = 'Tier 2') THEN th.edit_date END AS tier2_assignment,
       c.type
  FROM tickets AS c
  JOIN ticket_changes AS tc ON c.ticket_id = tc.case_id
  JOIN ticket_history AS th ON th.history_id = tc.history_id
 WHERE th.new_value = 'Tier 2';
```

My results are blank created_by and created_date columns.

Any tips for making this work? Am I close? Am I being unreasonable? Am I taking crazy pills? Thanks!

EDIT: Mock data as requested:

```
tickets
ticket_id        created_by  description  account_id       contact_id       product
========================================================================================
5005000000o9rju  jdoe        Test 1       00150000016Vvvm  0035000002h4nli  blue  widget
5005000000wNy8l  hgranger    Test 2       0015000000nTLiI  0035000002urMIs  green widget
50050000012kaoG  wadama      Test 3       0015000001Jc3DW  00350000031HSVD  green widget

ticket_changes
history_id       ticket_id
===============================
017500000U6HU4y  5005000000wNy8l
017500000U6HU4z  5005000000wNy8l
017500000U6ICyS  5005000000wNy8l
017500000MY0WoU  5005000000o9rju
017500000MY0WoV  5005000000o9rju
017500000MY0hhV  5005000000o9rju
017500000MY0hhW  5005000000o9rju
017500000cCVboC  50050000012kaoG
017500000cCVboD  50050000012kaoG
017500000cCVbsW  50050000012kaoG
017500000cIDT8t  50050000012kaoG
017500000cIDXp6  50050000012kaoG

ticket_history
history_id       edited_by  edit_date            field_event  old_value         new_value
==============================================================================================
017500000cCVboC  jdoe       2018-02-03 17:43:00  Created.    
017500000cCVboD  jdoe       2018-02-03 17:43:00  Status      New                Pending Support
017500000cCVbsW  jdoe       2018-02-03 17:45:00  Status      Pending Support    Tier 2 Escalated
017500000cIDT8t  dsmith     2018-02-05 09:01:00  Status      Tier 2 Escalated   Pending Support
017500000cIDXp6  dsmith     2018-02-05 09:13:00  Closed.    
017500000U6HU4y  hgranger   2017-07-10 15:02:00  Created.    
017500000U6HU4z  hgranger   2017-07-10 15:02:00  Status      New                Pending Support
017500000U6ICyS  hgranger   2017-07-10 19:20:00  Closed.    
017500000MY0WoU  wadama     2016-08-22 12:28:00  Created.    
017500000MY0WoV  wadama     2016-08-22 12:28:00  Status      New                Pending Support
017500000MY0hhV  wadama     2016-08-22 12:46:00  Closed.     Pending Support    Tier 2 Escalated
017500000MY0hhW  ksmith     2016-08-22 12:46:00  Status      Tier 2 Escalated   Pending Support
017500000MY0hhW  wadama     2016-08-22 13:16:00  Status      Tier 2 Escalated   Pending Support
```

Comment: On First `Join`  `ON c.ticket_id = tc.case_id`
Instead of `ON c.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's my typo, I have `c.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id` in my query right now. My columns `create_date` and `tier2_assignment` columns are still blank.

Comment: Could you give some mock data to mock? let's figure out the problem.

Comment: @daniel.shih added mock data to the post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is great, thanks! I knew it was possible and couldn't have figured it out without your help. Thanks again! This might be another post, but any tips on dealing with a ticket that may have been escalated more than once? Now that I can see everything, I have noticed that some of these were escalated, returned and escalated again. The query is pulling the most recent of the history records only. This might not be possible (and might be asking too much of you) :)

Comment: Does that solution help you? : )

Comment: @daniel.shih, yes that solution on 2/8/18 was extremely helpful. I am running into an issue where it doesn't pull back values when some of the data hasn't yet been entered. This may be a limitation of sqlite, though. I think I need an outer join, to show the open date, even when there may not be a closed date, for example. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your Issue.You might use `like` and `%` to find your `new_value` data.

**EDIT**

Need to make `ticket_history` Join `ticket_changes` with `where` clause as subquery.

Because you need to get `ticket_id` by `where` clause,

You get `ticket_id` can join `ticket_history's history_id` then you will get the answer.

```
SELECT c.ticket_id, 
       c.created_by, 
       created_date.edit_date as created_date,
       tier2_assignment.edit_date  AS tier2_assignment,
       c.product
  FROM tickets AS c
  JOIN ticket_changes AS tc ON c.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id
  JOIN ticket_history AS th ON th.history_id = tc.history_id
  INNER JOIN 
  (
     SELECT edit_date,ticket_id
     FROM ticket_history 
     INNER JOIN ticket_changes
     ON ticket_history.history_id = ticket_changes.history_id
     WHERE new_value LIKE '%Tier 2%'
  ) AS tier2_assignment ON  tier2_assignment.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
     SELECT edit_date,ticket_id
     FROM ticket_history 
     INNER JOIN ticket_changes
     ON ticket_history.history_id = ticket_changes.history_id
     WHERE field_event LIKE '%Created.%'
  ) AS created_date ON  created_date.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id 
 WHERE th.new_value  LIKE '%Tier 2%';
```

You can see the link sample

[SQLFiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7a2ec/107)

Comment: That helped! Thanks so much. For some reason, the created_date is still blank, even if I use `LIKE`. Any tips on getting that to work? Regarding t.ticket_number, that was a fat finger. It should be ticket_id. I updated the query and it's still blank, unfortunately.